# Now, how can I screen-scrape such a html line (using java)?

Tags: java, html, parsing, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am trying to screen-**scrape**  a html page so I can extract desired valuable data from it and into a text file. So far it's going well until I came across this within the html page:

```
<td> <b>In inventory</b>: 0.3 &#107;&#103;<br /><b>Equipped</b>: -4.5&#160;kg
```

The above line in the html code for the page often varies. So it need to figure about a way to scan the line (regardless of what it contains) for the weight (in this case would be ***0.3*** and ***-4.5***) and store this data into 2 seperate **doubles** as of such:

**double** inventoryWeight = **0.3** 
**double** equippedWeight = **-4.5**

I would like this to be done using pure java; if need be, do not hesitate to notify me of any third-party programs which can be executed within my java application to achieve this (but please vividly explain if so).

Thank you a bunch!

Comment: what means varies? how does it change? what have you tried so fare?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it fully. Basically I am making my java application loop through the URL of a webpage from 1 - 1000 times each time with numbers incrementing (e.g. stackoverflow.com/500 then stackoverflow.com/501 etc...) So the line I want to search will not always be constant; and I was wondering if there was a to search this line regardless of what it contains (to avoid errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegEx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is usually a good solution for scraping text.  Parentheses denote "capturing groups", which are stored and can then be accessed using Matcher.group(). [-.\d]+ matches anything consisting of one or more digits (0-9), periods, and hyphens.  .* matches anything (but sometimes not newline characters).  Here it's just used to essentially "throw away" everything you don't care about.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = ".*inventory<\\/b>: ([-.\\d]+).*Equipped<\\/b>: ([-.\\d]+).*";
        String text = "<td> <b>In inventory</b>: 0.3 &#107;&#103;<br /><b>Equipped</b>: -4.5&#160;kg";

        // Look for a match
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        // Get the matched text
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            String inventoryWeight = matcher.group(1);
            String equippedWeight = matcher.group(2);

            System.out.println("Inventory weight: " + inventoryWeight);
            System.out.println("Equipped weight: " + equippedWeight);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However like I said the line wouldn't be constant (it varies). How would you apply this to the String text? Could you "throw-away" parts of the String and only detect a decimal?

Comment: Try `String regex = ".*([-.\\d]+).*([-.\\d]+).*"`.  But that's pretty general, so it might match text that you don't want.

Comment: Can you give some examples of different lines that have to be matched?

Comment: Honestly there's too many to list. But the most recent I've came across was: `<td> Less than 1&#160;kg`. Well, thank you for your help - I'll just make do with `String regex = ".*([-.\\d]+).*([-.\\d]+).*"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this piece of html as String? If so, just search for `<b>Equipped</b>`. Then get `<b>Equipped</b>` end char position plus one. And then build new string by appending char by char until it's not a number or dot.

When you have those numbers in String variables you simply convert them to Doubles by using `double aDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString)`

Comment: I was thinking of something among the words of that. But i realise that this way wouldn't be very scalable (as the line will vary a lot - it might not even contain the words Equipped or Inventory.